# three js shadow clapping?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shadow

The shadows are weird.
Shadows are normally output only in certain areas.
What happend?

mycode:

```js
// plane
export const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500),
  new THREE.ShadowMaterial({ opacity: 0.5 })
)
plane.rotation.x = Math.PI * 1.5;
plane.receiveShadow = true;

// model
const [model, idle, walk /*, run*/] = await Promise.all([
  loader.loadAsync('/assets/models/man/man.fbx'),
  loader.loadAsync('/assets/models/man/idle.fbx'),
  loader.loadAsync('/assets/models/man/walk.fbx'),
])
model.traverse((m) => { m.castShadow = true; })

// light
export const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 2)
light.castShadow = true;

// renderer
export const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
```

[test img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjunr.png)